# Xcode 8.1 Autocompleting trailing closures

Tags: xcode

after updating Xcode to 8.1, I have issues with the autocompletion of trailing closures. From previous versions of Xcode, hitting return would automatically 'set up' the trailing closures for us to complete it. Some screenshots as such:

Once Im at the closure portion, I hit 'return' and it should set it up for me, but it did not.

[Before hitting 'return'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9LHH.png)

[After hitting 'return'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6IRv.png)

Prior to updating, it would help to set it up such that we can fill in the code nearly directly without typing out the curly braces etc, like such:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) in
    //code
}
```

Has anyone encounter this as well?

Comment: Try double clicking it with your mouse

Comment: @Roee84 nope, tried it as well. It gives the same result as hitting the 'return' key.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Xcode. As a workaround select your closure first (`Tab key`) and press `Enter`.